# Automatically update Entity instance from class MVC 3

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I've got a class that closely resembles one of my entities (I use the class for JSON de/serialization because the entity fails conversion to JSON, one of the known gotchyas of JSON + MVC).

Once I deserilize a JSON string into my object, is there a way to automatically update the associated Entity model instance.  The property names are the same.

e.g.

```
'myDeserialized is the deserialized JSON object coming over the wire
Dim entityInstance As DLL.Person = db.getPersonById(myDeserialized.id)
myDeserialized.update(entityInstance)
```

Where this just goes through and takes all the properties in `myDeserialized` and updates the same named property in `entityInstance`?

Or is it possible to just iterate over a key-value pair of all the properties in an object/entity?

I'm looking for something like `TryUpdateModel()`, but that only works with forms, right? I don't want to tie my data to a form, that's all.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what type and version of EF you use, but there are very powerful functions for iterating on the entities properties. Which mean you can easily make your update function on the entity  or its baseclass' partial (`entityInstance.Update(myDesrialized)`).

If you use `EntityObject`, then you can get an [`ObjectStateEntry`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectstateentry.aspx) for your entities and via this class you can very easily achieve this.

Please let us know what version and type of EF you use (POCO?)

Comment: Thanks for the pointers.  How do I find which version of EF I'm on? And I'm not sure what you mean by type.  Sorry for the confusion.